# Sample code for using mac camera in a program?

Tags: cocoa, language-agnostic, macos, camera

I'd like to use the camera in my Macbook in a program. I'm fairly language agnostic - C, Java, Python etc are all fine. Could anyone suggest the best place to look for documents or "Hello world" type code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ImageKit framework in Leopard has an [`IKPictureTaker`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/IKImagePicker_Class/IKImagePicker_Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/IKPictureTaker) class that will let you run the standard picture-taking sheet or panel that you seen in iChat and other applications.

If you don't want to use the standard picture-taker panel/sheet interface, you an use the [QTKit Capture](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTKitCaptureProgrammingGuide/) functionality to get an image from the iSight.

Both of these will require writing some Cocoa code in Objective-C, but that shouldn't really be an obstacle these days.

Comment: I'll be glad to see some example code if anybody achieves that. Perhaps directly through ctypes?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to manipulate the camera directly from your code, you must use the QuickTime Capture APIs or the [Cocoa QTKit Capture](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/QuickTime/Conceptual/QTKitCaptureProgrammingGuide/Introduction/chapter_1_section_1.html) wrapper (much better).

The only caveat is: if you use a QTCaptureDecompressedVideoOutput, remember that the callbacks aren't made on the main thread, but on the QuickTIme-managed capture thread. Use [someObject performSelectorOnMainThread:... withObject:... waitUntilDone:NO] to send messages to an object on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

There is a utility called isightcapture that runs from the unix command line that takes a picture from the isight camera and saves it.

You can check it out at this web site: http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/18598

An example of using this with AppleScript is:

tell application "Terminal"
   do script "/Applications/isightcapture myimage.jpg"
end tell

Answer (score 1):

From a related question which specifically asked the solution to be pythonic, you should give a try to [motmot's camiface](http://github.com/motmot/pycamiface) library from Andrew Straw. It also works with firewire cameras, but it works also with the isight, which is what you are looking for.

From the tutorial:

```
import motmot.cam_iface.cam_iface_ctypes as cam_iface
import numpy as np

mode_num = 0
device_num = 0
num_buffers = 32

cam = cam_iface.Camera(device_num,num_buffers,mode_num)
cam.start_camera()
frame = np.asarray(cam.grab_next_frame_blocking())
print 'grabbed frame with shape %s'%(frame.shape,)
```

It is used in this [sample neuroscience demo](http://www.incm.cnrs-mrs.fr/LaurentPerrinet/SimpleCellDemo)

Answer (score 0):

Quartz Composer is also a pleasant way to capture and work with video, when it's applicable.  There's a video input patch.

Quartz Composer is a visual programming environment that integrates into a larger Cocoa program if need be.

http://developer.apple.com/graphicsimaging/quartz/quartzcomposer.html

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is [OpenCV+python](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/cookbook.html) with a script like:

```
import cv
capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
img = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
```

Cannot do any simpler!